# How to analyze specific string of text from PDF in python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nltk, text-classification

I am working on some code that identifies named entities (NERs) in PDF documents. My current code works in three steps. First, it turns the PDF into a text string. Second, it tokenizes the text. Third, it classifies the text.

Right now, this code classifies every token (word) in the text string. However, I want the program to classify only a certain portion of the text. The portion is always located between the words `"Body"` and `"Classification"` (for those who are familiar with the format, I am analyzing LexisNexis documents). I am wondering if there is a way to tell the program to only classify the text between these two words? I've read several articles on this, but I have not been able to find an answer to my specific question.

I have the feeling that I need to insert a line identifying the specific string between the `"tokenized_text"` and `"classified_text"` line, but I'm not sure what. Thanks for your help!

```py
#Import Programs for NER
import os
import PyPDF2
import nltk
import pandas

# NER tagger
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger('C:\\file_path\\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       'C:\\file_path\\stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')

destDirectory = file_path

#Tagging NERs
for file in os.listdir(destDirectory):
    pdf_file = open(destDirectory + '\\' + file, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    text = ''
    for i in range(0,number_of_pages):
        page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        text = text+page_content
    tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
    classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

Edit:

Here is a simpler code to work from. Note, this program will not run unless you have the Stanford tagger `(St)` downloaded and set the file location.

```py
#Import Programs for NER
import os
import PyPDF2
import nltk
import pandas

# NER tagger
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger('C:\\file_path\\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                       'C:\\file_path\\stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')

destDirectory = file_path

#Tagging NERs
for file in os.listdir(destDirectory):
    # Insert code here for reading in the PDFs
    text = 'Title Example Body This is an example line of text. Classification Language: English'
    tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
    classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

Comment: If the PDF reading part works to your satisfaction, please remove it from the sample code so that just the text reading part remains, and provide a short extract of that plain text (as short as possible to test with; there's no need for several KB's of data). That way we do not have to copy your folder structure and set of PDFs and hope we get the same text as you do.

Comment: Just added simplified code at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex as shown below to extract the word you want to tag:

```
>>> import re
>>> s ='sample line Body WORD TO EXTRACT Classification'
>>> re.search(r'Body(.*?)Classification', s).group(1)
' WORD TO EXTRACT '
```

For multiple occurrences you can use `re.findall`